# WebDriver's WebElement sendKeys() method does not work with input-field

Tags: html, selenium, input, webdriver

I have an input field like the following:

```
<input class="..." maxlength="..." title="..." size="..." value="..." name="..."/>
```

This looks like an text input field, but there is no type-attribute. I am trying to clear the content of the field and write something into it.

```
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("abc");
```

The problem is that both methods don't work. I am asking myself if the missing type="text"-attribute is the problem or not. If not, why does this not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `click()` on that element before `clear()` & `sendKeys()`.

Comment: I used By.className(). This works correct. Only writing things to the element does not work.

Comment: i tried it and it worked. but the odd thing is it also works now without that click. don't know why.

Comment: best thing is to test it on another machine and be sure that the input field isn't changed. sometimes also selenium had strange behavour (like to use a command 2times so that it worked finally). Btw I'm new, if you wan't to rate me good please do it at the answer, comment ratings don't count :) thanks!

Comment: i did, but to be exactly the right answer is in the comment, not in the answer itself ;-) but i don't care.

Comment: I've gone ahead and moved the answer from the comments to the answer itself.